# "behavior for somebody" or "behavior of"?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> Lying is typical behavior for narcissists.

Can I replace "for" with "of"? Why or why not? Does the meaning change?

Online I found conflicting evidence:

> 1. With new people — people whom she hadn’t yet antagonized; people she might still be able to manipulate — she could seem merely eccentric. This is, apparently, typical **[behavior for](https://medium.com/coffee-house-writers/you-cant-kill-a-narcissist-with-kindness-c9053159af52)** narcissists.
> 2. "This is not unusual [**behavior for** narcissists](https://books.google.it/books?id=JMuOCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=%22behavior%20for%20narcissists%22&source=bl&ots=xWeoLdDCnr&sig=ACfU3U1wa7go8T0PIF3t7A-5ssFOQsn4og&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRtbrKn9CCAxVyif0HHfvbBLgQ6AF6BAhdEAM#v=onepage&q=%22behavior%20for%20narcissists%22&f=false) for whom others become non-persons–they literally cease to exist in their minds–once they have stopped being useful."
> 3. "Impulsivity and the Self-Defeating [**Behavior of** Narcissists](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1207/s15327957pspr1002_4)"
> 4. The hot and cold **[behavior of](https://medium.com/@mynarc/narcissists-are-hot-and-cold-the-contradictory-nature-of-narcissism-7a98f878fa6)** narcissists reflects their fluctuating moods and motivations, which are often driven by their selfish and manipulative agenda.

Is there a difference in meaning? Is it more formal to talk about the *behaviour **of** somebody* or the *behavior **for** somebody*?

Comment: Sometimes, you have to look up the "little" words...

Answer (score -1):

behavior **of** narcissists= the behavior they have or exhibit

typical behavior **for** narcissists=concerning or with respect to narcissists

**Merriam Webster:**

7
: **with respect to : CONCERNING**
a stickler for detail
heavy for its size

Answer (score -1):

**for**  can express the notion "proper to".

> Crying is a way of communicating *for* infants.

**of** can have the same meaning.

But that similarity of meaning does not indicate that the words can be plugged into a sentence interchangeably and be *equally* idiomatic:

> Crying is a way of communicating of infants.

The latter is grammatical and understandable but a little bit "off".

Perhaps the difference is one of *characteristic manner* (**for**) versus *intrinsic attribute or property* (**of**), though that difference is subtle.

> Crying is the communication of infants.

This version with **for** would be "off":

> Crying is the communication for infants.

Yet all we need to do to fix it is to remove the definite article:

> Crying is communication for infants.

Comment: That's what I said - *what what we **expect** them to do (what they **should** do).* But I don't know if that's the part of my answer a couple of people disagree with.

Comment: Maybe they got hung up on "more neutral"?

Comment: Well, you've said essentially the same as me regarding the ***for*** version. Presumably you wouldn't have written that unless you thought that the ***of*** version connotes something identifiably different. I don't really care about what some anonymous downvoting wally thinks (for all I know, not even native Anglophones). But I'd be interested to know if *you* think "neutral" is a useful descriptor there.

Comment: No, I don't think "neutral" is useful. If I understand you correctly, by it you mean non-judgmental.  Is that right?

Comment: Well, I didn't specifically mean "non-judgemental" - i just meant *behaviour of X's* is a straightforward descriptor, with no particular implications of *anything* ("judgemental" or not). And I must admit I understand nothing whatsoever from your comment. Regardless of what ***I*** thought I was conveying by the term, I haven't got a clue why you think it's "not useful" (I don;t even know if you mean "irrelevant", or "incorrect" or something completely different! :)

Comment: Anyway, you'd only written a couple of lines when I posted my first comment and upvoted your answer. But now I see that you're entirely concerned with contexts involving ***communication*** rather than OP's ***behaviour***, I've had to cancel it. The "syntactic affordances" of ***of*** and ***for*** are different, ***but so are*** the "syntactic affordances" of of ***communication*** and  ***behaviour*** (however spelled).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Actually I'm not concerned with "communication" per se but with examples of things where the one preposition or the other sounds "off".

Answer (score -2):

The "syntactic affordances" of ***of*** and ***for*** are different, and imho *Lying is typical behavior **of** narcissists* is idiomatically invalid. You need an indefinite article...

> *Lying is **a** typical behavior of narcissists*

Other than that, the ***of*** version is a more "neutral" assertion about what narcissists actually do. The ***for*** version (where the indefinite article is *optional*<sup>1</sup>) carries implications of lying being what what we ***expect*** them to do (what they ***should*** do).

The example context isn't ideal for this distinction, since the *specific* behaviour (telling lies) is never really "appropriate" for anyone.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Obviously, if ***a*** is included before ***typical behaviour***, this implies the existence of *other* "typical behaviours", even if you don't intend to actually specify them.

Comment: In cases like this, I usually assume downvotes are from AmE speakers objecting to my BrE usage preferences. But in this case, the spelling difference makes it easy to compare [AmE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+typical+behavior+of%2Cis+a+typical+behavior+of&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) to [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+typical+behaviour+of%2Cis+a+typical+behaviour+of&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10). Showing that Americans are actually much keener to observe my preference than Brits!